# How to compare dynamic string with static string in object with regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search

Let say I have one object with key as string which consists dynamic values-

```
let obj = {
"/prodp/v1/engagemnt/{engID}/doc/{docID}":"roles_1",
"/prodp/v1/engagemnt/{engID}/review/{reviewID}": "roles_2"
}
```

I want to compare and find value for below string from above object.

```
/prodp/v1/engagemnt/1234/doc/doc_1234
```

So as per requirement above string should return **roles_1** value from object.
Can anyone suggest the solution for this issue?

Comment: is ```{engID}``` is a simplification that mean we can have different id or is really the string inside the object ?

Comment: In place of {engID}, we can have different ID's.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.keys(obj)` to get all keys of an object as an array of string.

```
const obj = {
"/prodp/v1/engagemnt/{engID}/doc/{docID}":"roles_1",
"/prodp/v1/engagemnt/{engID}/review/{reviewID}": "roles_2"
}
let roles;
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
   // key will be equal to "/prodp/v1/engagemnt/{engID}/doc/{docID}":"roles_1" then it will be equal to the next key of the object
  roles = // do your regex here for whatever you want to check
});
```

Comment: I am looking for Regex that can compare and give me the required role for a specific URL from object.